# Fetched data in child component does not update on page change

Tags: fetch, components, sveltekit

I have a page:
`src/routes/[pageid]/+page.svelte`
and a file
`src/routes/[pageid]/page.js`

The `page.js` fetches data from an API and shows correctly on `+page.svelte`.

Inside `+page.svelte` I have another component `src/components/pagesection.svelte`

The `[pageid]/+page.svelte` page loops over that `PageSection` component and passes the `{section}` as a `data` attribute.

When I change the page (which is dynamic). The `{section}` in the child component does not update.

### +page.svelte

```js
import PageSection from '../../components/PageSection.svelte';

export let data;
$: ({pageData} = data);


{#if pageData}

  <h1>{pageData[0].attributes.Title}</h1>

  {#each pageData[0].attributes.sections.data as section}
    <!-- this updates here -->
    <h4>Section ID: {section.id}</h4>

    <!-- but not in here-->
    <PageSection data={section} />
  {/each}

{/if}
```

### PageSection.svelte

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import {ApiUrl} from '../stores.js';

export let data;

let SectionID = data.id;
const SectionApiURL = `${ApiUrl}/api/sections/${SectionID}populate=article`;
let sectionDetails;

onMount(() => {
  fetch(SectionApiURL)
  .then(response => {
       if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
       } else {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
       }
     })
     .then(data => {
          sectionDetails = data;
      })
     .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem fetching the page data:',error);
  });
});
```

Any help would be so appreciated. This seems like it should be such a basic thing to do for any website but I have spent hours trying to find out how to get the page information to change inside the component.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that, inside the `PageSection` component, you only fetch section details when the component is initially mounted, when what you really want to do is fetch section details whenever the `data` prop updates.

You can easily fix this (also, took the opportunity to switch to a more modern async/await syntax):

```js
import { ApiUrl } from '../stores.js';
export let data;

$: sectionDetails = updateSection(data) // will run whenever data updates

async function updateSection(section) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${ApiUrl}/api/sections/${section.id}?populate=article`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    }
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was a problem fetching the page data:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, you are my new best friend...

I added this:

let sectionDetails;
let sectionDetailsPromise;

$: sectionDetailsPromise = updateSection(data).then(data => {
  sectionDetails = data;
}) // will run whenever data updates, and now can get the data, is this good practice?

Comment: You're welcome! I feel like there is redundancy in your chosen solution? If your plan is to consume `sectionDetails` directly in the HTML section of your component, you might want to look into [`{#await ...}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) blocks rather than handling promise resolution in the script section. If you plan on using `sectionDetails` directly in the script section, consider changing `updateSection()` to return a value rather than a promise (replace `return response.json();` with `const details = await response.json(); return details;`).

Comment: But utlimately this is cosmetic, what really matters is that your code works as you intended it to.

Comment: Yes I understand your point and again thanks, it is more cosmetic but I like a clean HTML and more organised login the script section. So less script code in the html the better for me, but thats just a personal preference.